# How does Uplink fast improve the Spanning Tree Protocol?

Tags: networking, routes, switching, spanning-tree

What improvement to the Spanning Tree protocol is provided by the “Uplink Fast”
solution?

Answer (score 0):

Uplink Fast helps when a switch has multiple uplinks (towards the core of the network) by allowing the switch to skip the Listen/Learn states when recovering from failure of the root port and changing the alternate root port from Blocked to Forwarding.